# Can a root node be considered as a leaf node if it has no child node?

Tags: tree, theory

My problem is to find how many leaf nodes there are in a given tree. I know how to count leaves of a tree but I am confused about whether or not the root node should be considered as a leaf node if there is no child to the root node?

Note: I have browsed on internet for the specific question but no one has given the answer to the my point. So I am asking here.

Comment: By the general definition of the leaf, yes.

Comment: This is an academic question, and I'd say a "root node" without children is just ... a node ... but as soon as you consider it a special case of a tree, yes, that's a leaf node.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation.